# Selenium error "Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms" when running on jenkins master node

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

So after I compile my selenium code and run the file.class Im getting the following error

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:112)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at ClusterReloadAut.<clinit>(ClusterReloadAut.java:11)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
Error: no display specified

Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'bijenkins-ngwb.svl.ibm.com', ip: '9.30.4.102', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at ClusterReloadAut.<clinit>(ClusterReloadAut.java:11)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:112)
    ... 7 more
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Im running the code on Jenkins master using the following commands

```
javac -cp selenium-java-2.53.0.jar:selenium-java-2.53.0-srcs.jar:selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar myfile.java

echo $USERNAME 
echo $PASSWORD 
echo $CLUSTERNUM 
echo $IPADD

java -cp .:selenium-java-2.53.0.jar:selenium-java-2.53.0-srcs.jar:selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar myfile $USERNAME $PASSWORD $CLUSTERNUM $IPADD
```

Please let me know if more details needed

Comment: are you using firefox version 47.0 or less ?

Comment: try to use firefox v47.0.1 and selenium-firefox-driver v2.53.1

Answer (score 1):

Use this code block, to initiate Firefox driver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("http://www.google.com"); 
driver.quit();
```